# Getting Error After Web Element Inspection

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have checked Google for this error. But the solution has not been very helpful. I would appreciate your help, please.

The URL of the webpage that I am trying to automate is: https://www.starwoodhotels.com/preferredguest/account/sign_in.html

The code that I have written up to automate the login page is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StarWood_Hotels_Valid_User_Login
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate Firefox Driver
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.starwoodhotels.com/preferredguest/account/sign_in.html");

            //Enter User Name - AutoTest1
            var user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("userName"));
            user.SendKeys("AutoTest1");

            //Enter Password - Testing123
            var pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("userPassword"));
            pass.SendKeys("Testing123");

            //Click on submit button 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("actionLink right")).Click();

        }
    }
}
```

=======================================================================

I have used HTML elements from Firebug to identify the necessary web elements.

========================================================================

Here is the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
```

Additional information: Unable to locate element: #userName

Comment: You have got the id's all wrong. first learn how to get the id's correctly from the html code. you have used the classname(userName & userPassword) in place of id's (login & password)

Comment: I used XPath & I got the right Id... Sorted.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did an inspect on the page and I think that you're looking for the wrong element. The html is (I removed the unnecessary code):

```
<div class="userName">
   <input tabindex="1" name="login" id="login" type="text" size="12" maxlength="70" value="" class="logintextbox textField validate " data-validationrules="isRequired,omnitureTrackingFrontEnd" placeholder="Username or SPG number">
</div<>
...
<div class="userPassword">
  <input name="password" tabindex="2" id="password" type="password" size="12" maxlength="128" value="" data-validationrules="isRequired,omnitureTrackingFrontEnd" class="logintextbox textField validate " placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

You should look for the input to send keys and not the div. And you're using `By.Id()` and the correct is `By.className` in this case.
And I'm not sure if the `var user = ...` is correct too since I always use `WebElement user = ...` .

I suggest you to try the code below:

```
//Enter User Name - AutoTest1
WebElement user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
user.SendKeys("AutoTest1");

//Enter Password - Testing123
WebElement pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
pass.SendKeys("Testing123");

//Click on submit button
driver.FindElement(By.Id("checkSubmit")).Click();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

This is the error message I get when I run your code:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'WebElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) StarWood_Hotels_Valid_User_Login c:\users\xxxx\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\StarWood_Hotels_Valid_User_Login\StarWood_Hotels_Valid_User_Login\Program.cs 20 Active

Comment: This error is during compiling time? You'll have to import the WebElement library. In java is `import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;` In your case may be `using OpenQA.Selenium.WebElement`.

Comment: Merci beaucoup....

Yes, the error ocurred during compiling (run) time.

I tried importing Selenium.Webelement. But I was not able to locate it.

Comment: Are you using C#? The correct is to use `IWebElement` instead  `WebElement`. Please remove the `using OpenQA.Selenium.WebElement`

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** I think you have taken the wrong id for username, password, signIn.
as suggested by @Thiago. Update your code with the right ids.

**Secondly,**
"NoSuchElementException" happens when the driver is not able you find the webelement.
In your case , as soon as you are navigating to the page. You are trying to enter the username and password.
I would suggest go to the page, wait for the webelements to get loaded, then enter the username and password.You can try the below code.

```
//Initialise to WebDriverWait to wait for 30 seconds before throwing the "NoSuchElementException"
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver , TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

//This will wait for the WebElement 'user' till it is loaded and visible.
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("login")));
```

Then you can enter the username , password and click on SignIn button

```
//Enter User Name - AutoTest1
WebElement user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
user.SendKeys("AutoTest1");

//Enter Password - Testing123
WebElement pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
pass.SendKeys("Testing123");

//Click on submit button
driver.FindElement(By.Id("checkSubmit")).Click();
```

Comment: Thank you so much...

The 1st code produced the error: The Type or Namespace 'WebDriverWait' name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?

Many thanks once again.